# Where does TeamCity store its meta-runner data?

Tags: teamcity

I want to download all the XML files which define my company's meta-runners, en-masse. Where would I find these? Are they in flat files or the database?

I don't want to have to copy and paste from the UI. I have looked in the Api's application.wadl file and have not located any reference to "runners".

Comment: by `runners` do you mean build configurations?

Comment: @daggett I'm referring to the meta-runners which are custom XML configurations created by user/admins. They are then used as steps within a build configuration.
They can be found here http://[your TeamCity base url]/admin/editProject.html?projectId=_Root&tab=metaRunner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whereas I liked very much the answer that [Didier Aupest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3416072/didier-aupest) gave, it did not directly answer the original question.

TeamCity Support has let me know that all configurations, including templates, meta-runners, etc, are stored in the data directory for the server. Specifically, meta-runners are in `config\projects\[project name]\pluginData\metaRunners`.

The data directory's path can be seen in the `Global Settings` of the `Administration` page in TeamCity.

Comment: This is by far the most correct answer, even 2+ years later.

Answer (score 0):

When you set the "Versioned settings", you can attach a VCS Root.
This will store the data inside a repository, and you will be able to navigate through this data in XML, or Kotlin style.
[Storing Project Settings in Version Control](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Storing+Project+Settings+in+Version+Control)